# Multinomial Probabilities (Counting Problem)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question:
We draw $n$ balls out of a hat. At each draw there is a probability of $p_i$ of getting a ball of color $c_i$. What is the probability of obtaining exactly $n_i$ of each ball of color $c_i$? Note that $n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_r = n$.

Answer:
I am trying to understand the answer to this problem. It's broken into two parts and I don't quite understand the second part.

We know that drawing a particular sequence of balls containing exactly $n_i$ of color $c_i$ balls is 
$$p_1^{n_1} + p_2^{n_2} + \cdots + p_r^{n_r}$$

The solution says "the number of possible sequences containing $n_i$ balls of color $c_i$ is the number of ways to form a partition of n distinct slots into subsets of cardinality $n_1, \cdots n_r$. Therefore, our answer is

$$\dbinom{n}{n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_r} p_1^{n_1} + p_2^{n_2} + \cdots + p_r^{n_r}$$

I understand the first part with the probabilities, but I don't understand why the multinomial coefficient counts all the possible sequences. Could someone demonstrate a simple example with the $2+1+1 = 4$, where our colors are red, blue and green?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** up, you multiply, rather than add, to get the probabilities of the sequence.
$$\dbinom{n}{n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_r}\times p_1^{n_1} \times p_2^{n_2} \times \cdots \times p_r^{n_r}$$

**Second**: Consider this example from the results of flipping 2 coins.  The ways to get 1 head and 1 tail are: HT, TH, and the ways *not* to get exactly one of each are: HH, TT.  Clearly then the probability of getting 1 of each is $\frac 12$

And by the multinomial distribution: $\displaystyle \mathrm{\large P}(H=1, T=1) = {2\choose 1,1} \left(\tfrac 12\right)^1 \left(\tfrac 12\right)^1 = \tfrac 12$

That's all it is.  The probability of getting the numbers of each atomic event (*the product*), times the number of permutations that yield the same result (*the multinomial coefficient*).

**Third**

> Could someone demonstrate a simple example with the 2+1+1=4, where our colors are red, blue and green?

There are ${4\choose 2,1,1}=12$ permutations of this sequence.

There are $n!=24$ ways to rearrange $n=4$ objects, but these are subgrouped into equivalent cases. There are $2!$ ways to rearrange $2$ *distinct* ball, but only $1$ way to select $2$ *non-distinct* balls, et cetera.  So we need to divide by $n_r!\times n_b! \times n_g!=2$

$${(n_r+n_b+n_g)\choose n_r, n_g, n_b}=\frac{(n_r+n_b+n_g)!}{(n_r!\times n_b!\times n_g)!} \\ = {4\choose 2,1,1} = \frac{4!}{2!1!1!}= 12$$

These sequences are: RRBG, RRGB, RBRG, RBGR, RGRB, RGBR, BRRG, BRGR, BGRR, GRRB, GRBR, GBRR

The probability of getting RRBG (in that order) is $\mathrm{\large P}(RRBG) = p_r^2 \times p_b\times p_g$, and it is the same probability for getting each of those sequence.

So the probability of getting any of those sequences is (that is, RRGB in *any* order) is $\mathrm{\large P}(R=2,B=1,G=1) = 12\times p_r^2 \times p_b\times p_g$

Comment: Thanks! It makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Addition is wrong (see the answer of Graham).

If you have $n=n_{1}+\dots+n_{r}$ colored balls, then
they can be put in $n!$ orders. For every pattern of colors there are $n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{r}!$
of these orders that result in this pattern. So to count the distinct
number of the patterns you should divide $n!$ by $n_{1}!\times\cdots\times n_{r}!$.